# Ansible keeps trying to interpolate variable despite condition being false

Tags: ansible

I am trying to perform a couple of tasks within a block as follows:

```
- name: site.yml --> Handle existing' user's public SSH keys

  block:

  - name: site.yml --> Get client's existing public SSH key
    shell: "aws iam list-ssh-public-keys --user-name {{ client_name }}"
    register: rv_keylist

  - name: site.yml --> Conditionally delete client's public SSH key
    shell: "aws iam delete-ssh-public-key --user-name {{ client_name }} --ssh-public-key-id {{ item.SSHPublicKeyId }}"
    loop: "{{ (rv_keylist.stdout | from_json).SSHPublicKeys }}"

  when: rv_client_exists.rc == 0 and renew_client_key == 'True'
```

However despite the fact that the `when` clause evaluates to false as shown from the output below, the task fails because `ansible` tries to interpolate a non existing variable and of course fails

```
TASK [site.yml --> Get client's existing public SSH key] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 05 April 2019  22:23:41 +0300 (0:00:01.800)       0:00:08.818 ********** 
skipping: [127.0.0.0] => changed=false 
  skip_reason: Conditional result was False

TASK [site.yml --> Conditionally delete client's public SSH key] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 05 April 2019  22:23:41 +0300 (0:00:00.063)       0:00:08.882 ********** 
fatal: [127.0.0.0]: FAILED! => 
  msg: 'Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ (rv_keylist.stdout | from_json).SSHPublicKeys }}): expected string or buffer'
```

How can anyone address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by two things:

1. The way a `block` operates is that the `when` condition is applied individually to each task in the block (it does not cause the entire `block` to be skipped).
2. The behavior of `when` is different depending on whether or not your task has a loop.

For a non-looping task, like your "Get client's existing public SSH key" task, a `when` condition determines whether or not Ansible should skip the **task**.

For a looping task, `when` determines whether or not Ansible should skip a particular **iteration** of the task. In other words, the `loop` command is still evaluated, which is why you're getting this particular error.

You could work around it like this:

```
- name: site.yml --> Handle existing' user's public SSH keys
  when: rv_client_exists.rc == 0 and renew_client_key == 'True'
  block:

    - name: site.yml --> Get client's existing public SSH key
      shell: "aws iam list-ssh-public-keys --user-name {{ client_name }}"
      register: rv_keylist

    - name: site.yml --> Conditionally delete client's public SSH key
      shell: "aws iam delete-ssh-public-key --user-name {{ client_name }} --ssh-public-key-id {{ item.SSHPublicKeyId }}"
      loop: "{{ ((rv_keylist.stdout|default('{}'))|from_json).SSHPublicKeys|default([]) }}"
```

This makes use of the `default` filter in a couple of places to ensure that `loop` statement always has valid data. In the event that `rv_keylist.stdout` isn't available, the whole expression will evaluate to an empty list.

Comment: that was some useful and hard to find information; another way is to entirely skip evaluation of registered variables and corresponding task execution via appropriate usage of `tags`

Comment: @larsks: The braces are quoted in *default('{}')* and the brackets are not in *default([])*. Why?

Comment: Because we are passing the first expression to `from_json`, which expects a *string*.